# Declare variable with date function in standard SQL bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can we declare variable as a date function? e.g. I want to declare yesterday date as a SQL function

```
#Standard SQL

DECLARE yesterday DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE() - 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in your question is the way to go!
But if for some reason you need to have it as a function - consider below

```
create temp function yesterday() as (
  current_date() - 1
);
select yesterday()
```